# GXT3 TextButton styling

Tags: gwt, gxt

How can I change the styling/appearance of a TextButton in EXT GWT 3 ? 
I am mostly interested in the background color.

Thank you, Horatiu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GXT 2x was easier ... but ... GXT 3 is supposed to be easier to maintain for large projects.

Sencha gives different ways for GXT 3 but the one I think I will use is to create an appearance and then pass it in via a constructor.  Here is their example:

```
ContentPanel redContentPanel = new ContentPanel(new RedContentPanelAppearance());
```

The complete example is at:
[Sencha's explanation and reasoning](http://www.sencha.com/blog/migrating-styles-and-themes-from-ext-gwt-2-to-gxt-3/)

Think you have to create your own appearance (based off an existing one and changing the bit you want)  Not trivial it seems.

More reasoning on the Appearance usage is at [gxt3 appearance explanation](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-appearance-design)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the style classes defined in ButtonCellBase.css and override them in your css.